# How to test a method in viewModel which returns LiveData value from repository

Tags: android, unit-testing

In my ViewModel I am calling a method from my repository class which returns a LiveData from a webservice. My viewModel code:

```
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(val mainRepository: MainRepository) : ViewModel() {
   val source: LiveData<My_Result> = mainRepository.fetchApiresultFromClient(str_query)  
       .......... }
```

My question is that is there a way to get real data from the webservice called in repository or do I just prepare the result and assert that its not null; something like below:

```
when(mainrepository.fetchApiresultFromClient(any(String::class))).thenReturn(myPreparedLiveData<My_result>)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the question is tagged as unit-testing, IMHO, expecting real data from a web service does not actually fall into the scope of unit-testing. You might call than an integration testing, however, from the unit-testing point of view, you might consider mocking the response from the function that calls the web service and verify if the method was called using proper arguments that you expect.

Comment: thanks. But is it still possible to get the real data from a web service or from local DB/sqlite by using integration test?

Comment: Yes of course. You just have to set up a test database then. So that for a specific service call returns you a specific data and you can assert that.